# No users can ssh using keys into recently upgraded CentOS 7 machines

Tags: centos, ssh, sshd

We have two servers that we just upgraded to CentOS 7 and ever since then, none of our keys work to ssh into them for any of our users, it always goes to passwords.
This doesn't happen with our other servers and it also didn't happen with CentOS 6 on these same machines. I've checked the permissions of the .ssh directory and the authorized file folder, which are the most common, then I found when googling this problem, but all the files in .ssh are owned by the correct users.

No other answer in google or StackExchange has helped, since they all boil down to a typo or a permissions issue. The output looks very similar/identical to the one provided in this question ([Why is SSH key authentication failing for this user? (CENTOS 7)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421397/why-is-ssh-key-authentication-failing-for-this-user-centos-7)), but the solution that worked for them did not work for us, since I don't get a permissions error when using ssh-copy-id.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

EDIT: More pertinent info:

- The updated servers are running OpenSSH_7.4 whereas our other servers that people are trying to ssh from are running OpenSSH_5.3
- Here's the ssh -vvv output (edited):
  `OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
  debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
  debug1: Applying options for *
  debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
  debug1: Connecting to {servername} [159.28.23.7] port 22.
  debug1: Connection established.
  debug1: identity file /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/identity type -1
  debug1: identity file /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
  debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/id_rsa.
  debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
  debug3: key_read: missing keytype
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
  debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
  debug3: key_read: missing keytype
  debug1: identity file /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
  debug1: identity file /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
  debug1: identity file /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
  debug1: identity file /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
  debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH*
  debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
  debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  debug3: Wrote 864 bytes for a total of 885
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
  debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
  debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
  debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
  debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
  debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
  debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 909
  debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 152/320
  debug2: bits set: 1019/2048
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
  debug3: Wrote 272 bytes for a total of 1181
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host {servername} filename /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/known_hosts
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host {servername} filename /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/known_hosts
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 159.28.23.7 filename /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/known_hosts
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 159.28.23.7 filename /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/known_hosts
  debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
  debug1: Host '{servername}' is known and matches the RSA host key.
  debug1: Found key in /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  debug2: bits set: 1035/2048
  debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
  debug2: kex_derive_keys
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
  debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1197
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
  debug3: Wrote 52 bytes for a total of 1249
  debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  debug2: key: /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/identity ((nil))
  debug2: key: /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f769e632270)
  debug2: key: /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
  debug2: key: /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
  debug3: Wrote 84 bytes for a total of 1333
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
  debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
  debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
  debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
  debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
  debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Trying private key: /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/identity
  debug3: no such identity: /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/identity
  debug1: Offering public key: /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/id_rsa
  debug3: send_pubkey_test
  debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
  debug3: Wrote 628 bytes for a total of 1961
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
  debug1: Trying private key: /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug3: no such identity: /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug1: Trying private key: /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  debug3: no such identity: /{home directory}/{username}/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
  debug3: authmethod_lookup password
  debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
  debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
  debug1: Next authentication method: password`

EDIT 2: Also worth noting, it doesn't seem to happen with local users, only ones with their user directories in a location shared between all our servers.

Comment: Restore the previous `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and check logs.

Comment: When you run `ssh-keyscan <hostname>` what is the output? is it a key  or null?

Comment: SSH algorithms are evolving with time....The question could benefit of having more technical details  *and*  an ssh debug output.

Comment: @Goro The output is `{hostname} SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4` and then the server's rsa key

Comment: Did you try to delete the folder `.ssh`, and then create it again, after then generate new rsa keys? You can run the following commands: 1) `rm -rf ~/.ssh` 2) `mkdir ~/.ssh` 3) `cd ~/.ssh`  4) `ssh-keygen -t rsa
"choose no passphrase when asked and accept the default filename of id_rsa"` 5) `scp id_rsa.pub <user>@<yourhost>:.ssh/authorized_keys` Provide your password when asked .

Comment: @Goro yep, tried that, didn't help.  One thing i figured out is that our old servers and our updated ones are running different version of OpenSSH (5.3 vs 7.4); could that be causing it?

Comment: "...user directories in a location shared between all our servers" Are you using encrypted home directories by any chance? Or some other arrangement where the user's home directory isn't accessible until they log in?

Comment: We've narrowed it down to an issue with PAM.  We use LDAP for user management and we noticed in some logs after we did some deeper digging that there were some PAM related errors, like "cannot create session: file or directory not found" before creating a session anyway, and "password failed" without us typing a password.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being mostly unrelated PAM itself.  The problem was actually an interaction with SELinux, which we don't normally use and which we think was installed and activated by default.  Setting it to Permissive mode fixed the issue immediately and users can use their keys again.